# SSIS update the destination database

Tags: ssis

I need to  update the value in a sharepoint list   if one the list item values is submitted  using SSIS

Sharepoint list Columns
1) Status
2) Text

The Destination and Source Sharepoint List are the same.
 If the value in the List item is Submitted i need it to update the Text Column
 I have the Sql query to update the  value

```
UPDATE       dbo.SharePoint
SET                Text = { fn CONCAT(Text, '1') }
WHERE        (FormStatus = 'Submitted')
```

1) I added a sharepoint list source and a sharepoint destination
2) I have created a Connection manager using SpCred.
3)  Where do i add the update query .
I can change the caml query in the Component queries  to just get the items that are 'Submitted' . but how do i  update the list.

Is there a better way to do it using SSIS

Comment: Can't you just use UPDATE       dbo.SharePoint
SET                Text = Text + '1'
WHERE        (FormStatus = 'Submitted')

Answer (score 0):

This solution is applicable **only** if your sharepoint list source and destination are 2 different tables.

1. Start with a Source connection - get only Submitted values and go to 3, or go to step 2 if you are getting all the rows.
2. Put a `Conditional Split` With a condition: `(DT_STR,50,1250)[FormStatus] == "Submitted"`
3. Add a `Derived Column` component, with `<replace ...>` property. Drag the existing column value into expression field and add the text you want.

   `(DT_STR,50,1250)[FormStatus]+"1"`
4. Finish with Destination Connection and proper column mapping

Otherwise (1 sharepoint table you want to modify) please just use an `SQL Task` in Control Flow, with the update you wrote.